# Zephyr to Test Rail migration - Is it possible?

Tags: excel, testing, jira, jira-zephyr, testrail

We are currently looking at Testrail as an alternative to using the Zephyr plugin within JIRA as Testrail looks to give us better test case and reporting management than Zephyr does.

Currently faced with the usual problem when changing tools of how to migrate our existing test cases from one to the other.

I know there are importer tools to get Excel spreadsheet cases into Testrail, so that is ok.
The problem I'm facing is how to get the test scripts out of Zephyr.

Does anyone know of any similar plugins to export test cases/scripts from Zephyr to Excel?

I've tried using the inbuilt export function, but it only seems to export the basic case details, not the individual test steps.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some further investigation myself, it appears there are multiple ways to extract parts of the tests from Zephyr.

1. If you use the 'Search' function to locate a test and then choose to Export via the Export button in the test case frame itself then you get a summary of the test information but WITHOUT the test steps.
   If you use the 'Search' function to locate a test and then choose to Export via the Export button in the test case frame itself then you get a summary of the test information but WITHOUT the test steps.
2. If you use the Export button from the top of the window (there should be 'Share', 'Export' and 'Tools' buttons) you get additional options.
   Selecting the option for 'Excel (All fields)' will extract full test case information, including all the fields.
3. A slightly quicker way to extract them is to Search for executed tests and from the 'Executed Tests Summary', select a test via the checkbox next to the test and select 'Export'.
   This gives the option to extract the test information, including test steps, as CSV, XLS, HTML, XML or RSS.

As stated above, this is a large file and the test step information not readily apparent. (My steps were started in column CH!)

It is also worth noting that each line within the test step appears in a different cell, so importing to another tool will definitely require a lot of reformatting of the test step information.

Comment: Adding the tests to TestRail is fairly easy but will require a lot of cutting down of the exported files to a smaller template which will go into TestRail.

Answer (score 0):

the inbuilt export definitely exports the test steps. I am looking at my own exported test cases with test steps right now in xls and csv formats

However the export has many many columns, the test step part is easy to miss.

In my XLS  the test steps are in columns BF, BG, and BH. Of course yours are likely to be different, I am only giving you those column names as an example of how many columns you will have to scroll past.

- XLS:  For example test case EX-123 with 4 steps there will 4 rows merged together until the test steps col. So the "key", "Summary" columns will be 4 rows merged together..
- CSV:  The all the info is on the 1'st row.. and then at the test step column each test step has a row.

Just take a test case you know has steps, and start to scroll right through the columns and you'll see the steps .

Comment: Thanks Dan. Managed to do some more playing about myself and got an answer which I've listed below. Seems that there are multiple places to Export with varying results. :(